# How do I fix this: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Tags: errors

Here is the line that is effecting my site from loading...I am just getting a blank page for my site.  Please help as my business site is obviously down.  Thank you in advance to whomever can help me.

$bg = (!$bgimage == '') ? 'style="background-image:url'("".$bgimage[url].'")' : '';

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$bg = (!$bgimage == '') ? 'style="background-image:url'("".$bgimage[url].'")' : '';
```

There's a confusion with the quote marks. You're closing your `'` too early, but it's really hard to see in a construction like this. (Also, the array index needs to be wrapped in quotes, either single or double.)

```
$bg = (!$bgimage == '') ? 'style="background-image:url("'.$bgimage['url'].'")' : '';
```

might clear up the PHP error, but I'm not sure it'll still do what you want it to. There's still some confusion with quote marks in the CSS; also, is `$bgimage` a string or an array?

I'd recommend not using the ternary operator, in this case, to make the code more readable.

```
$bg = '';
if ( ! empty( $bgimage ) ) {
    $bg = 'style="background-image:url(\'' . $bgimage['url'] . '\')";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pat! Your edits fixed the site as it now loads...whew!  So here is more of the code so you can have a better idea.  Also, it is supposed to load a background image that I upload as part of my page creation if I so choose to use one of those layouts for the page.

Comment: Rather than editing an answer to ask further questions, please [ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This keeps the questions and answers encapsulated.